# Smooth scrolling animation to sections of page in IE on Windows Phone

Tags: jquery, windows-phone

I have a page with various sections and links to those sections. I have implemented scrolling animation with the following:

```
$(function() {
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') &&      location.hostname == this.hostname) {
  var target = $(this.hash);
  target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
  if (target.length) {
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 1000);
    return false;
  }
}
});
});
```

This works perfectly in Chrome, Safari, Firefox and on iOS 7 and Android, but on Windows Phone (8 with IE) the scrolling is jerky and the top of the section is out.

Any ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

IE has a bug with the smooth scroll feature and animations not firing until after the scroll.

It is on by default for all win8 users of IE11.

Here is what I use to fix the jerkeyness on fixed header.

```
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident\/7\./)) {
    $('body').on("mousewheel", function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        var wd = event.wheelDelta;
        var csp = window.pageYOffset;
        window.scrollTo(0, csp - wd);
    });
}
```